# Kendo UI MVC multiple groupings in a single line on a grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui

I would like to know how complicated is to grouping everything is just one line.

Let's say

```
                             .Group(g => g.Add(c => c.GradeCode))
                             .Group(g => g.Add(c => c.SizeLength))
                             .Group(g => g.Add(c => c.SizeWidth))
                             .Group(g => g.Add(c => c.SizeThick))
```

Would be instead of having 
Grouping in **(GradeCode >  SizeLength > SizeWidth > SizeThick)** depth 4, just having a grouping of depth 1 **((GradeCode AND SizeLength AND SizeWidth AND SizeThick) >)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kendo Grid does not support the requested behavior. Multiple groups are nested in each other.

Comment: It seems that you are right, the workaround I used was not a good practice at all, but was the only one I have found.
I created a field on the database with these 4 fields concatenated and later on I grouped by this new field.

Comment: I did something similar but not at the database level. I modified the DTO object I was sending from the server and binding to the grid to have the composite property. This allowed me to isolate the change to the DTO and grid binding.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate all the fields in a new field, and group by it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used server operation and I've existing multiple groups 'Model.Request.Groups' stored in session.
after refreshing the page, I can restored these groups by this...

```
.Group(g =>
    {
        foreach(var item in Model.Request.Groups)
            g.Add(item.Member, item.MemberType);
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).